# Inserting text with \cleardoublepage and memoir

Tags: memoir, double-sided

When I wrote my first template using `book`, I used the following macro to add text to blank pages:

```
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
  \clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
  \hbox{}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \begin{center}
    \textit{This page intentionally left blank}
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \newpage
  \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi
}
```

The same macro does not work under `memoir`, blank pages are not printed anymore. Even just copy-pasting the `\cleardoublepage` definition from the class' source (as opposed to the macro above) is enough to break it.

How can I port my macro to `memoir`?

Minimal (non-working) example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright,final]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\settrims{0pt}{0pt}
\setlrmarginsandblock{2.54cm}{2.54cm}{1.618}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.54cm}{2.54cm}{1.618}
\checkandfixthelayout

\title{StackExchange test}
\author{Amyspark}
\date{\today}

\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
  \clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
  \hbox{}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \begin{center}
    \textit{This page intentionally left blank}
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \newpage
  \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi
}
\renewcommand{\cleartorecto}{\cleardoublepage}

\begin{document}
  \SingleSpacing
  \frontmatter

  \begin{titlingpage*}
    \maketitle
  \end{titlingpage*}
  \cleartorecto % the back side of the title page should be blank (but instead no page)

  \OnehalfSpacing
  \tableofcontents*
  \cleardoublepage % same as above


  \mainmatter
  \chapter{Test}
  \lipsum[1-6]

  \section{Objectives}
  \lipsum[7-8]

  \section{First section}
  \lipsum[2-3]
  \subsection{Sub}
  \lipsum[3]
  \subsubsection{Subsub}
  \lipsum[4]\Parencite[4]{Foley:2008:CGC:1481349} % or any suitable cite, just to generate bib


  \backmatter
  \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc] % this should go in a recto page (but it doesn't)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code also work with `memoir`. If text is ended on odd page, code insert on the even page "This page intentionally left blank" and than continue on odd page. Please, provide small document which will show oposite result.

Comment: I've added the example. Please have a look at it. Thanks

Comment: Try adding `\makeatletter`.... `\makeatother ` around your redefinition. It contains macros with @ in the name, those are special, and you have to tell latex you want to use those

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the manual, `memoir` includes commands `\movetoevenpage`, `\cleartoevenpage`, `\movetooddpage` and `\cleartooddpage`, each of which can take an optional argument which will be printed on the skipped page (if there is one). The `\moveto...` macros stop printing the current page and then continue typesetting on the next appropriate page; the `\clearto...` commands are similar except that they will flush any floats before continuing typesetting. For example:

`\cleartooddpage[\vspace*{\fill}THIS PAGE LEFT BLANK\vspace*{\fill}]`

will put THIS PAGE LEFT BLANK in the centre of any potential skipped (empty) even numbered page.